# Outlook VBA to sync calendar to Exchange

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking for a way to force Outlook 2010 to sync the calendar entries back to Exchange.

**Background**: I have a button in the ribbon that syncs specific calendar entries back into a SQL database. When the user adds a new entry and clicks the button directly after creating the appointment, the new entry is not available on the Exchange server yet. If the user waits for ~30 seconds the tool is able to find the new entry. Outlook syncs the data every n seconds.

The mentioned button calls a macro, the opens a browser and does some other stuff. I've been digging through the Outlook API, but wasn't able to find a method that will force-sync the calendar back to Exchange. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

**Edit**:
Invoking the Update Folder button on the calendar folder (see screenshot), does exactly the thing I want (the other buttons don't). But I can't find a way to invoke that via macro.

[image: Outlook Send and Receive]

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate pressing ribbon buttons with [ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx)

Untested as the button does nothing for me.

```
Private Sub ExecuteMso_UpdateFolder()

    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx

    Dim objNS As Namespace
    Dim objExpl As Explorer
    Dim objFolder As folder

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer

    If Not objExpl Is Nothing Then
        Set objFolder = objExpl.CurrentFolder
        objExpl.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("UpdateFolder")
    End If

End Sub
```